# API not sending email

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a rest API that will ask for an email, subject and message from the user and send that subject and message to the email provided in the email field, from the email registered in the settings.py file.

My models.py is as follows:

```
class Email(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=False)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

my views.py is as follows:

```
class EmailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EmailUser

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Email.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

serializer.py file looks something like this:

```
class EmailUser(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'subject', 'message')

    def send_email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        return send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)
```

and urls.py is as follows:

```
url(r'email-user/', csrf_exempt(EmailView.as_view({'post': 'create', 'get': 'list'})))
```

I expect that it will send the email to the provided email address but as I do POST call the email, subject and Message is stored in the database but email isn't sending to the provided email.

I am newbie in django rest framework if someone could tell me exact what I am doing wrong in this will be quite helpful.

Comment: You are not calling `send_email_user()` anywhere...are you?

Comment: Where should I call that function?
Can you please explain a little

Comment: ok. Let me ask you one thing. When you wanna call it?

Comment: As the user fills the form with "email", "subject", and "message" and press post button in api then email should be sent to the email provided along with subject and message entered.
I have tried to add a method in views but it didn't do anything like this:
`
      def post(self):
        EmailUser.send_email_user()
`

Comment: @BismaSheikh Can you please provide email settings? In your localhost (dev environment) the email is not sent, instead the content of the email will be dumped to your console..

Comment: @mariodev here are the email settings that is written in settings file
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'bisma.ahmed320@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abcdef.321'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

Answer (score 1):

[A ViewSet doesn't have a post method](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

> A ViewSet class is simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create().

You could try using CreateModelMixin and ListAPIView instead.

views.py

```py
from rest_framework import generics, mixins

class EmailAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = EmailUser

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Email.objects.all()
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        subject = request.POST.get('subject')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        from_email = request.POST.get('from_email')
        user = # Do some logic to get your user here
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [user.email], **kwargs)
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_serializer_context(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {'request': self.request}
```